# How to continuously compare the database time with current time in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a notification services, so I continuously need to check the database time values with the current time and put the notification. What is the way to achieve this. I am building this in php and backend is mysql. Please let me know the solution as I am a newbee to php
Let me clear it out.. 
I know the query.. but i need to know the way that will be continuously checking those values

Comment: MySQLi::query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE time < " . time() . " ORDER BY time ASC");

Comment: @Richard.. i know the query.. i need the solution on how this query should be continuously executed to send the notification when the database time matches with current time

Comment: With a loop like while or for. Better solution maybe is a cronjob which is called every minute or less.

Comment: sorry but I didn't get it.. can you elaborate it more?

Comment: If you need to run the script continually you have several options. 1. create a cron job and run it every one minute and check the db time and current time and send notification. 2. More advanced technologies like beanstalkd could also be used.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: I think a cronjob is the best and easiest method here. He is a PHP newbie and I do not think that he has a own server, but only a webspace. So beanstalkd is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to create a cron job where it executes your script every so often.
Another method would be to have an infite loop running:

```
<?php
  while(true) {
    //Compare time in database,
    //If time matches up, do something...
    //Else...
    sleep(60); //Sleep for 60 seconds. Then repeat.
}
```